# Javascript delay not working. Tried too many things

Tags: javascript

I am new with JavaScript programming. I am making a program for deaf and blind children community. It is text to display Letters program. It split text and show image on screen.

### How it works:

HTML and JavaScript base program. Input sentence taken from user. JavaScript split it and send relevant image name to HTML for display.

### Problem:

It shows all images at once without delay. When I use alert() it shows all images are being displayed. 3rd day going on I tried to implement delay timebase substraction or settimeout but not working. Perhaps I am doing something wrong. I need community help to fix this.

### Code:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <title>Image Changer</title>
  </head>
// How to change image SCR through javascript.  

<body>

<input id="txt" name="txt" type="textbox" />

<img id="image1" src="./multimedia/alphabets/0.jpg" style="width:100px">

<button onclick="imagechange((document.getElementById('txt').value) , document.getElementById('image1.scr'))">Button</button>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function imagechange(txt,image1){
    
        var txt1 =  "";
        var txt2 =  "";
        var imagefolderlocation = "./multimedia/alphabets/";        
        for (var i = 0; i < txt.length;i++) {
                txt1 = txt.charAt(i).toUpperCase();

        alert(txt1);    
        document.getElementById('image1').src = imagefolderlocation + txt1 +".jpg";
        if(txt1 == " " )
             document.getElementById('image1').src = imagefolderlocation + "Blank.jpg";

        }
    }
    
    
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeout` is async so that's probably the reason it did not work. To make it work, you can do something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       function delay(time) {
         return new Promise(function(resolve) {
           setTimeout(resolve, time);
         });
       }

       async function imagechange(txt,image1){
         var txt1 =  "";
         var txt2 =  "";
         var imagefolderlocation = "./multimedia/alphabets/";        
         for (var i = 0; i < txt.length;i++) {
                txt1 = txt.charAt(i).toUpperCase();
                await delay(1000);   
                document.getElementById('image1').src = imagefolderlocation + txt1 +".jpg";
                if(txt1 == " " ) document.getElementById('image1').src = imagefolderlocation + "Blank.jpg";
        }
    }
</script>
```

I made a delay promise from the `setTimeout` and made your `imageChange` function async so I can await the delay promise during each loop.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is because DOM manipulation is synchronous and DOM rendering is asynchronous. Actually you can try this:

```
function imagechange(txt,image1){
    var txt1 =  "";
    var txt2 =  "";
    var imagefolderlocation = "./multimedia/alphabets/";        
    for (var i = 0; i < txt.length;i++) {
        txt1 = txt.charAt(i).toUpperCase();

        alert(txt1);    
        document.getElementById('image1').src = imagefolderlocation + txt1 +".jpg";
        if(txt1 == " " ) document.getElementById('image1').src = imagefolderlocation + "Blank.jpg";

        console.log(document.getElementById('image1').src);
    }
}
```

You can see the result in the console, `image1.src` did change but was not rendered.
To make it work, you can use the asynchronous function like this if you are using ES5:

```
function imagechange(txt,image1){
    var txt1 =  "";
    var txt2 =  "";
    var imagefolderlocation = "./multimedia/alphabets/";
    for (var i = 0; i < txt.length;i++) {
        txt1 = txt.charAt(i).toUpperCase();

        // Use closures to avoid the problems caused by the txt1 variable context
        function imageChange(imageName) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                document.getElementById('image1').src = imagefolderlocation + imageName +".jpg";
                if(txt1 === " " ) {
                    document.getElementById('image1').src = imagefolderlocation + "Blank.jpg";
                }
            }, 1000 * i);  // Change image1.src after i seconds
        }
        imageChange(txt1);
    }
}
```

Btw, you should use `<!-- How to change image SCR through javascript. -->` in HTML if you want to add comments.

Comment: i found my shortfalls in above replies. all solution worked and works like charm. thank you all fellas.